# 404.php в битрикс выдаёт HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, битрикс

настроен чпу. Все страницы работают. Но при попытке перейти по несуществующему адресу получаю вместо файла 404.php , HTTP ERROR 500.

вот файл .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

  #php_value display_errors 1

  php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
  php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
 php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
 # php_value display_errors 0
 php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
 php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
 php_value error_reporting 2039
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Пробовали в конце отрабатывать ошибки? Может он у вас просто в бесконечный цикл уходит?

Comment: Просто вроде насколько я помню после правила errorDocument апач пройдёт дальше по правилам, и возможно ваше правило фурычит с каким то из mod_rewrite

Comment: Приведите код файла 404.php из корня сайта. Разкомментируйте строку `#php_value display_errors 1` может увидите ошибку. Что в этот момент пишется в логи апача?

Comment: @NikolajSarry да Вы правы в 404.php была синтаксическая ошибка. Спасибо!